# Spring configuration of C3P0 with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring, c3p0

I have a Spring/JPA application with Hibernate as the JPA provider. I've configured a C3P0 data source in Spring via:

```
<bean id="myJdbcDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
  <!-- Connection properties -->
  <property name="driverClass" value="$DS{database.class}" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="$DS{database.url}" />
  <property name="user" value="$DS{database.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="$DS{database.password}" />
  <!-- Pool properties -->
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
  <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
  <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
  <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
```

I then specified this data source in the Spring entity manager factory as follows:

```
<bean id="myLocalEmf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myapp-core" />
      <property name="dataSource" ref="myJdbcDataSource" />
 </bean>
```

However, I recently noticed while browsing maven artifacts a "hibernate-c3p0". What is this? Is this something I need to use? Or do I already have this configured properly?

Comment: Why it's a [protocol droid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3P0) of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hibernate-c3p0.jar provides the class `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`, a C3P0-based implementation of the Hibernate `ConnectionProvider` contract. You need this artifact when you want to use C3P0 as Hibernate's standalone connection pool (that you configure through the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file). Since you're using Spring, you don't need it.

Comment: Is there ever any reason / advantage that might mean using the hibernate-c3p0 version is a better idea, or are they functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0 looks like the module you would use if you were configuring Hibernate to use C3P0 directly.

You shouldn't need it assuming the configuration you posted works for you - does it?

Comment: What do you mean you can't be too sure? Either it works, or it doesn't.