# Spring + Hibernate + Spring

Tags: database, hibernate, spring, pool, c3p0

I've a project of Spring and Hibernate, but that use a lot of conections to my database (MYSQL). I know that I should implement a C3P0 to manage Pool conection but i dont know how?. Plase take me a help.

Hibernate's config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/oasis"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="mysql"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
         <list>
            <value>com.app.oasis.model.base</value>
         </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
         </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Where do I have to add the C3P0 config?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002899/spring-configuration-of-c3p0-with-hibernate ? Your question appears to be an exact duplicate.

Comment: that isn't duplicate. In my case i dont have any idea how to add the c3p0 code. x_x

Comment: Go for hikariCP, It is having high performance than c3p0.

Answer (score 1):

Add the C3P0 jar file (download from [c3p0 website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) or use maven) to your classpath and create your dataSource using `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/oasis"/>
    <property name="user" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="mysql"/>
    <!-- Various configuration properties can be set here -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Right on! I'm pretty sure though that c3p0 jar comes standard with Hibernate.

Comment: Ok. That run but the other properties where should set?