# Hibernate c3p0 and Spring. Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, c3p0

I'm currently developing an application that uses hibernate and Spring MVC.
I want to implement c3p0 but I can't understand how to implement it.

I used the c3p0 jars in the optional folder, `Hibernate-c3p0-5.0.2.jar` and
`c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar`.

These are my configurations.

Right now, I'm using `DriverManagerDatasource` from Spring.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

I tried doing this

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!-- C3P0 Config -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="100" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="10" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
</bean>
```

but i'm getting an error.

```
Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
```

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driverClassName` is a `DriverManagerDataSource` property, not a property on the `C3P0ConnectionProvider`. So that's why you're getting the error.

Instead of using the Spring `DriverManagerDataSource`, which is just a simple `DataSource` implementation and not a connection pool at all, you want to use C3P0's `DataSource` implementation. Try using `ComboPooledDataSource`. That implementation also has a `driverClassName` property, which you will want to set equal to your *database* driver (like MySQL driver or whatever).

Here's an example that I lifted off a [web page](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/12/c3p0-connection-pooling-example):

```
    cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //loads the jdbc driver
    cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
    cpds.setUser("root");
    cpds.setPassword("root");
```

That's not Spring, but just make the adjustment to put it in Spring. The full class name is `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`. You can see a Spring-based example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002899/spring-configuration-of-c3p0-with-hibernate).

Comment: Hi. finally made it work thanks, but i still have a question, if I use com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource that comes from c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar, then what's the use of Hibernate-c3p0-5.0.2.jar?

Comment: Hibernate provides a basic connection pooling mechanism for dev/test purposes, but it's not intended for production. That jar allows you to use Hibernate's connection pooling, backended by c3p0. But for production you would forgo the Hibernate connection pooling and just use a "real" connection pooling DataSource like what c3p0, Hikari, etc. provide. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#d5e154

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is old but for the newbies, hope it helps.
The problem is with your name tags

replace:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
```

with

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

...
```

Please note: **driverClass** is used instead of driverClassName, **jdbcUrl** is used instead of url, **user** is used instead of username  and **password** is at it was..... these are the parameters for ComboPooledDataSource
HOPE IT HELPS